# Where is the option to do a GIT MERGE in Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013, git-merge, team-explorer

I have committed a changeset on my local machine.  There are 13 incoming commits.  When I attempt to 'Sync', I get an error message that says:  "2 uncommitted changes would be overwritten by merge."

I am sure that there is a manual merge option, but I can't find it anywhere...

Can somebody point me to some instructions that tell where this manual merge option is?

This is using a GIT repository from inside Visual Studio Team Explorer 2013.

Thanks,
Curtis

Comment: This is a bug in Visual Studio 2013.  Please update to Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-apr-2-vs.aspx

Comment: Did that a couple days ago..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

Looks like I had a couple files that I was 'Excluding' from checking in.  GIT doesn't like that.  Visual studio doesn't tell you that it's a problem.

So I went to the command line and did a manual "git commit" on the command line.  When I did that, GIT told me which files were actually causing the conflict in the merge.

They were .dlls in my case which I build.  So I just undid my changes to them them and was able to successfully merge.

I really wish Visual Studio Team Explorer would be a bit more helpful with their messages.

I figured if I excluded files from my checkin that it wouldn't consider them as conflicting.

Oh well, problem is solved now.

Comment: Indeed, we should be more informative here.  Any files that have uncommitted changes locally will block a merge that would also write to those files, so that you will not lose data.  It sounds like you should not be committing DLLs and should have them in `.gitignore`, though.

Comment: Normally, yes.  However, in this case, I'm building some .dlls in one project that will be used by another project, so I have a post build copy that puts them into a .lib folder, and we checkin the contents of the .lib folder when we make changes to it, so other apps can use those .dlls.

Comment: Sounds like Nuget might still be useful here.